# Disable the secure information from header

Tags: php, apache, security, cakephp, web

In my application(developed by PHP) using some ajax calls, So in every ajax call Request header there is some information about the website like

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:500
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 16 Feb 2015 10:44:39 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server : Apache/x.x.10
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.15
```

So i want to disable the information about server & x-powered by etc. I googled for this issue and got alink [Disable x-powered by](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/16/apache-tips-tricks-hide-php-version-x-powered-by/). If i will set the variable in php.ini file

```
expose_php=Off
```

It's removing the content 'X-powered-By' and can we remove the web server information from request headers?

Comment: This is worth to check http://goo.gl/t4lodz

Comment: Your question is answered on the sister site here: [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/change-apache-httpd-server-http-header)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs and can be found on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is a bit off topic so I'll just leave this as a comment. You're looking for the headers_module in Apache, and although Apache no longer allows you to remove the Server header, you can rename by adding a line like this to your httpd.conf file: `Header set Server "MyServer"`

Answer (score 0):

To your httpd.conf

```
Header unset Server
ServerTokens Prod
```

You can unset many of the fields in the header but some are strict.